# How to use a bar chart as a "thermometer"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I created a Python script to extract sentiment in comments. Now I want to represent the general sentiment with three steps : negative, neutral and positive. I want to use a bar chart but with only one bar to act as a thermometer (the higher the bar is, the better the comments were) but I'm a bit stuck.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Bar chart
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
emotion = ['Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive']
percentage = [23,17,60]
width = 0.35

ax.bar(emotion,percentage)
ax.set_ylabel('Positivity')
ax.set_title('General emotion in comments')

# here it's wrong but I don't know how to perform what I want
ax.bar(1, percentage[0], width, color='r')  
ax.bar(1, percentage[1], width, color='b')  
ax.bar(1, percentage[2], width, color='g')  
###############################################
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-100, 100, 10))
plt.show()
```

In this case I have hardcoded that the comments were 23% negative, 17% neutral and 60% positive but I can't figure out how:

- to print the axis informations (here Positivity)
- use my `percentage` to draw the bar because at the moment I have three kind of bar but I want one bar

The bar chart I want to create is like this :

[image]

Thank you for the help

[EDIT]

Ok I changed a bit the code :

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
emotion = ['Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive']
percentage = [-23,17,60]
plt.title('General emotion in comments')
plt.xlabel(' ')
plt.ylabel('Positivity')
plt.ylim([-100, 100])
ax.bar(2, percentage[2], width=0.35, color='g')
ax.bar(2, percentage[0], width=0.35, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please clarify how you want to convert from the three percentages "positive," "neutral," and "negative" to a single value that you want to plot in your figure.

Comment: It will always be that `percentage[0]` is the percentage of negative comments I found

Comment: Yes, I understand. However, you have three values, but only want to plot one. How do you determine this one value that you are going to plot? Is it just the percentage of positive comments, the difference between positive and negative, some kind of average, etc?

Comment: Ahhh yes I didn't think like this... I think I need to use the biggest value, like if negative is biggest than the 2 others I plot negative, if neutral is bigger I plot neutral... or do you have any recommandations ?

Comment: It's your figure, so you should decide how to plot it. However, if you are plotting on a negative-to-positive axis, it does not really make sense to plot neutral percentages. You could consider plotting both a positive and a negative bar, one pointing in the positive y-direction and one pointing in the negative y-direction.

Comment: Yes that seems like a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the help I came out with

```py
x = 1   
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

emotion = ['Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive']
percentage = [-23,17,60]
plt.title('General emotion')
plt.ylabel('Positivity')
plt.ylim([-100, 100])
ax.set_xlim(0,3)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom=False, top=False, labelbottom=False)


ax.bar(x, percentage[2], width=0.35, color='g')
ax.bar(x, percentage[0], width=0.35, color='r')
plt.show()
```